# app rater not working correctly for me

Tags: java, android, class, rate

can someone check this app rater code and tell me how can I have it dismiss on a customer request but not come right back after customer presses same back button at least give them 5 tries before all the conditions are met, thank you

```
public class AppRater {
private final static String APP_TITLE = "name";
private final static String APP_PNAME = "com.code.code";

private final static int DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT = 1;
private final static int LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT = 1;

public static void app_launched(Context mContext) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("apprater", 0);
    if (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", false)) { return ; }

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    // Increment launch counter
    long launch_count = prefs.getLong("launch_count", 0) + 1;
    editor.putLong("launch_count", launch_count);

    // Get date of first launch
    Long date_firstLaunch = prefs.getLong("date_firstlaunch", 1);
    if (date_firstLaunch == 1) {
        date_firstLaunch = System.currentTimeMillis();
        editor.putLong("date_firstlaunch", date_firstLaunch);
    }

 // Wait at least n days before opening
    if (launch_count >= LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= date_firstLaunch +
                (DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT * 0 * 24 * 60 * 1000)) {
            showRateDialog(mContext, editor);
        }
    }

    editor.commit();
}  

public static void showRateDialog(final Context mContext, final SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle("Rate " + APP_TITLE);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
    tv.setText("If you enjoy using " + APP_TITLE + ", please take a moment to rate it. Thanks for your support!");
    tv.setWidth(600);
    tv.setPadding(24, 0, 24, 60);
    ll.addView(tv);

    Button b1 = new Button(mContext);
    b1.setText("Rate " + APP_TITLE);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });       
    ll.addView(b1);

    Button b2 = new Button(mContext);
    b2.setText("Remind me later");
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    ll.addView(b2);

    Button b3 = new Button(mContext);
    b3.setText("No, thanks");
    b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editor != null) {
                editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ll.addView(b3);

    dialog.setContentView(ll);       
    dialog.show();       
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something strange here

```
DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT * 0 * 24 * 60 * 1000
```

shouldn't be ?

```
DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

You can also use DialogBuilder button options instead creating button manually.
Here is an example :

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.rate_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
       });
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.rate_dialog_never, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

           }
       });
builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.rate_dialog_later, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

       }
   });
```